# sets in python 2.7 deprecated

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

It seems sets are deprecated in Python 2.7 and wondering what is the alternative for unordered unique collection? Thanks.

```
from sets import Set

a = Set()
a.add("1")
a.add("2")
a.add("3")

if "1" in a:
    print "1"
if "Hello" in a:
    print "Hello"
```

regards,
Lin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sets are still available in python 2.7 and are built in.

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a_set = set([1, 2, 3])
>>> a_set
set([1, 2, 3])
>>> b_set = {1, 2, 3}
>>> b_set
set([1, 2, 3])
```

Docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html
And see the Notice at the top of the page:

> Deprecated since version 2.6: The built-in set/frozenset types replace
>   this module.

Comment: Thanks tknickman, mark your reply as answer. Works for me. :)